# Exception in Executing Cypher Queries of Neo4j in Java Application

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I am new to Neo4j Graph Database and I want to create CyperQueries from  java Application . I am using the above neo4j manual

```
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-create.html
```

I am creating nodes from java APplication as follow

```
public class CreateQuery
{
    public static final String DBPATH="D:/Neo4j/CQL";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GraphDatabaseService path=new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DBPATH);
        Transaction tx=path.beginTx();
        try
        {
        Map<String, Object> props  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props .put( "Firstnamename", "Sharon" );
        props .put( "lastname", "Eunis" );

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put( "props", props  );

        ExecutionEngine engine=new ExecutionEngine(path);
        ExecutionResult result=engine.execute( "create ({props})", params );
        System.out.println(result);
        tx.success();
        } 
        finally
        {
             tx.finish();
             path.shutdown();

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the above error. I am not aware of this errors, please can any 1 help in solving as soon as posible .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.LRUCache.<init>(LRUCache.scala:30)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anon$1.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:84)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:84)
    at com.neo4j.CreateQuery.main(CretaeQuery.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the latest release of this library (ConcurrentLinkedHashMap for Java):

http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/files/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared works fine. I think the problem is with your import statements. They should be like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a library error. Perhaps you have imported the wrong version of something?

Just in case, I should point out that you are meant to use the GDB factory for building an embedded instance:

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

Not sure that it will make any difference.