# NoClassDefFoundError when executing a Neo4j Cypher query in Java

Tags: java, neo4j

I tried the following basic example about [executing Cypher queries from Java in embedded mode](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-java.html) as is, but it shows the errors below:

Code:

```
package test;

import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("D:/MI/Tools/neo4j-community-1.9.M02/test2");
        // add some data first, keep id of node so we can refer to it
        long id;
        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        try {
            Node refNode = db.createNode();
            id = refNode.getId();
            refNode.setProperty("name", "reference node");
            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }

        // let's execute a query now
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db);
        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start n=node(" + id + ") return n, n.name");
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.LRUCache.<init>(LRUCache.scala:30)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anon$1.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:91)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:91)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.<init>(ExecutionEngine.java:54)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.<init>(ExecutionEngine.java:44)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Is there any problem in the code?

(I use neo4j-community-1.9.M02 and NetBeans IDE 7.2.1)

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a dependency issue inside the neo4j cypher stuff. Make sure you have all of the dependency JARs in the right spot when executing.

Also, this problem is identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175176/exception-in-executing-cypher-queries-of-neo4j-in-java-application?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, I did find that similar question but the answer didn't help. I read in another question (now don't remember which is!) that adding a latest version of concurrentlinkedhashmap library could help, and it really helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem disappeared after adding the following Java library to the project

http://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/files/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar