# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder

Tags: java, orientdb

I am using OrientDB Native Java Driver for a simple connection to Orient DB Server. I am following [OrientDb Github link](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Object-Database) for basic setup instructions. I have added the five jars mentioned in the github link, `orient-commons-*.jar, orientdb-core-*.jar, orientdb-object-*.jar, orientdb-client-*.jar, orientdb-enterprise-*.jar`. However, I am still facing below error. I googled and couldn't find any answer regarding which jar file am I missing? Please advise.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.<init>(OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.java:22)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.<init>(OSBTreeCollectionManagerAbstract.java:28)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OSBTreeCollectionManagerRemote.<init>(OSBTreeCollectionManagerRemote.java:34)
    [... removed lines ... ] com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:54)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:54)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx.open(OObjectDatabaseTx.java:102)
    at org.poc.orientdb.jdbc.OrientJDBC.<init>(OrientJDBC.java:18)
    at org.poc.orientdb.jdbc.OrientJDBC.main(OrientJDBC.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: There is an  SO question  that points to using the jar file mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075957/noclassdeffounderror-when-executing-a-neo4j-cypher-query-in-java

Comment: Thanks. The jar mentioned in the link you provided is the same mentioned by Raghvendra in post below. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure whether this will help you or not but looks like the class you mentioned is in the "concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.1.jar"

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.1

Comment: My problem is resolved after adding the jar u mentioned. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to database
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder.maximumWeightedCapacity(J)Lcom/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder;  SOLVED with [concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar](https://concurrentlinkedhashmap.googlecode.com/files/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar)