# Import data from orientDB into SOLR

Tags: solr, orientdb

I want to import data from orientDB into SOLR using jdbc driver (http://orientdb.com/download) of orientdb.

But I don't know some things

1. name of orient jdbc driver (like org.postgresql.Driver, org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver)
2. transform orient response and map according to solr schema.

Comment: I found 1 answer name = com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver
am I right ?

Comment: May I ask why you want to migrate your data? Solr is basically Lucene which you can easily use in OrientDB. Please let us know first of all why a migration could be useful. Overall the JDBC Driver can used for this indeed.

Comment: Hey @kwoxer I want to implement solr for index, tokenization, fast search, and auto complete etc . and store data into orient.

Comment: This can all be done with OrientDB as well. Solr is way faster for sure but is not really needed for small project. When I was testing the speed or OrientDB, Neo4j and Solr with the same data. Solr was always he fastest of them but OrientDB was very close. But I tested with ~500 GB of data. Maybe you can talk a bit more about your task and project? And also what kind of data you want to store in OrientDB.

Comment: @kwoxer Yes that why i am using solr and orientDB together because according to our research orient is best db and solr is best search engine. 

I successfully add JDBC driver and configure it in solr. but now i am getting this error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137682/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-googlecode-concurrentlinkedhashmap-concurren
So how can i replace concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar file in orient jdbc driver ?

Comment: I can tell so much about the JDBC driver that one year ago I was running into the same troubles. The driver is not the best and without huge change in the development of this driver it will never change. I think you should engage in the project on Github and report those issues there. This is no issue of OrientDB itself. =)

Comment: @kwoxer thank you. I created issue on orient jdbc page.

Comment: I do not know OrientDB that much, but when skimming over their page I can see that the offer a REST API. This is something you can consume with Solr ([XML/HTTP Datasource](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2FHTTP_Datasource)).

Comment: Hi @kwoxer sorry for late reply. right now problem is orient is just sending JSON response and solr can import only XML data. so Thats why I am using JDBC driver of orientDB.